# Display the OSX Command symbol key in a JLabel

Tags: java, macos, command, key

We want to show a hint for a JList that the user can select multiple items with the platform dependent key for multiselect.

However I have not found any way to show the OS X COMMAND symbol in a JLabel, which means the symbol that's printed on the apple keyboard on the command key, also called apple key.

Here's a picture of the symbol I want to display on OS X. [image: COMMAND SYMBOL]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/Command_key.svg/120px-Command_key.svg.png))</sub>

Also I do want to have it platform independent.

I.e. something like

```
component.add( new JList() , BorderLayout.CENTER );
component.add( new JLabel( MessageFormat.format("With {0} you can " 
  + "select multiple items", 
  KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( ... , ... ) ) ) , BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Where instead of the *{0}* there should appear above seen symbol...

Does any one of you guys know how to do this? I know it must be possible somehow since in the JMenuItems there is the symbol...

My own (non graphical solutions) looks like this:

```
add( new JLabel( MessageFormat.format(
  "With {0} you can select multiple items" , 
  System.getProperty( "mrj.version" ) != null ? "COMMAND" : "CTRL" ) ) ,
  BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol in question is avaiable through Unicode, and the HTML character sets. All you need to do is make your JLabel display HTML by starting its text string with <html> and then include the character code.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( "<html>&#8984; is the Apple command symbol." );
```

This will work on a Mac, but I've no idea what it'll do on other platforms, although you do seem to have that covered off.

Comment: THank you for the hint, I will check that out tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 1):

As David points out, you can use the Unicode escape sequence `\u2318` although it must be displayed with a font supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks perfect. I assume you intend to factor out the hint code so you reuse it.

```
add( new JLabel( MessageFormat.format(
  "With {0} you can select multiple items", 
  getMetaKeyHint(),
  BorderLayout.SOUTH );

public String getMetaKeyHint() {
    return System.getProperty( "mrj.version" ) != null ? "COMMAND" : "CTRL" );
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be my intention. Although I'd prefer to show the COMMAND key _symbol_, which means the symbol that's printed on the keyboard on the apple/command key.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to check for the system and load accordingly

```
(System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase(Locale.US).indexOf("MAC OS X") == 0 )
```

Comment: Although your solution may also work, the mac developer guides state that the "proper way" to check wether your application platform is Mac OS X is checking the property "mrj.version" for a non-empty string. Annoying, eh? ;-)